# How to show a Drupal Openlayers map in a colorbox?

Tags: drupal, dictionary, colorbox, openlayers

We've been working on a project to show bus routes in a grid and have each column header link to the corresponding location on a map.  We're on Drupal 6 and already have both the Colorbox and OpenLayers modules installed.  I've been able to display a map inside a node using the CCK OpenLayers WKT field.

Ideally, this would use a colorbox that would appear with embedded OpenLayers map.  Is there a best way to have a link open a colorbox instance with the appropriate map embedded?  If the map is a node, is there a best way to show just node content inside a colorbox?

Any help would be appreciated.  We've played with some things, but just haven't really found a good way of accomplishing this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we've done in a similar scenario (popping up a video in Colorbox) was to create a [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/6) [override](http://drupal.org/node/173880) file specific to that content type with everything stripped out, except for the content we want displayed in the lightbox.

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like that's the way I'd need to go.  For now, I decided to just show image-based maps until we implement something more fancy down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing I found is that if you make the map layer default to fullscreen, it fills the colorbox